# Is it possible to use TFS (Without Test Manager) with open source test management tools?

Tags: test-management, mtm, tfs

Is it possible to use Team Foundation Server (Without Test Manager) with open source test management tools, for example Bugzilla as the management interface linking in with Team foundation server?

Back Story:

Due to the departmental budget we are unable to purchase Mircosft Test Manager so we are looking for a way of creating Test Plans/testcases and link them to the work items in TFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a new work item type called "Test", and customise it to have the fields you require. You will need to add fields like Result (Not Run, Passed, Failed, In Progress etc), Tested by, Date executed and Tested in Build, etc.

You will need to make these fields reportable in the data warehouse, and build some status reports.

Once you have done that, you can execute test cases within TFS, linked to your other work item types. I worked this way for years, actually prefer it to using MTM.

Comment: This is very interesting as i was told by the TFS owner that this would not work. Thanks for the info I will give it a go.

Comment: Yep it works .. install a local TFS basic install and look into template customisation.

Answer (score 0):

A google search reveals these tools:

This tool makes it easier to integrate TFS with external tools:
http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/

This tool has integration with both Bugzilla and TFS:
http://www.origsoft.com/products/qualify/tfs.php

Unfortunately, I don't see anything listed on the Bugzilla site itself:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Addons#Integration_with_Source_Code_Management_utilities

Answer (score 0):

If you're not afraid of coding a custom solution have a look at the TFS API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130307%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

You would then probably need to use Bugzilla's API (http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/api/) to do the integration if you need to link directly within Bugzilla itself.  If you're looking to link test cases in Bugzilla to work items in TFS I imagine you would need to add a foreign key in the database that maps to both the TFS ID and the Bugzilla ID for a particular item.

Answer (score 0):

[Enterprise Tester](http://www.enterprisetester.com/) offers support for integrating with TFS, allowing you to synchronize incidents (what they call defects/issues) between TFS and Enterprise Tester, as well as supporting the synchronization of requirements/user stories from TFS across to Enterprise Tester as well.

This allows:

- The creation of requirements in ET, synchronized back to work items in TFS.
- You can then create test scripts in ET, which are associated with the requirements.
- You can then execute the test scripts and log incidents (defects) during execution.
- The incidents raised are automatically synchronized back to TFS again as work items.

Though not free, a single-user starter license is $10.